# Push Notification doesn't call didReceiveRemoteNotification swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Push Notification using FCM.
When my app is in the foreground and a notification arrive then didReceiveRemoteNotification method is called but when the app is not active it doesn't call this method

I am checking this by setting a bool value to true when app is in background but doesn't change the bool it means it doesn't execute this line..
Here is my method.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo) { (UIBackgroundFetchResult) in
            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState != .Active{


            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "AriveNotification")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            }else{

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "AriveNotification")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            }
        }
    }


    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState != .Active{


            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "AriveNotification")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            }else{

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "AriveNotification")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            }
        }
        completionHandler(.NewData)
    }
```

For Registering GCM Push Notification i use these method when user sign in successfully.

```
func userDidLoggedIn() -> Void {
    tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! VaboTabBarController


    self.window?.rootViewController = self.tabBarController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    self.registerDeviceForPushNotification(UIApplication.sharedApplication())

}
func connectToFcm() {

    FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion({error in


        if (error != nil) {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }


    })
}
func application(application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox)
}


func registerDeviceForPushNotification(application:UIApplication) -> Void {

    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.init(forTypes: [.Alert,.Badge,.Sound], categories: nil)
    self.pushNotificationToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
    let userID = self.userData["id"] as! NSNumber

    print("InstanceID token: \(self.pushNotificationToken)")
    self.registerDeviceOnServerWith(self.pushNotificationToken, userID: userID)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}


func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {

        let userID = self.userData["id"] as! NSNumber

        self.registerDeviceOnServerWith(refreshedToken, userID: userID)
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
}
```

PS. I have set Remote-Notification check from capabilities as well as in info.plist. Plus i also have tried by adding `"content-available":1` from the notification payload.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the correct spelling and character placement in Notification Payload.
As per your statement you might have placed incorrect character in content available place.
Please send your payload in this format..

```
{
    "aps":{
        "alert":{
            "title":"Notification Title Text",
            "Body" :"Notification Body",
            "content_available":1

        }
    }
}
```

You have written `content-available` it should be `content_availble`. Now this will wake your app to run your logic in the background as well

Comment: Thanks bro, you are my hero